# Ubuntu 22.10 stuck on boot

Tags: boot

Upgraded to latest today and after reboot it never goes beyond this screen: https://ibb.co/JKWCNKV

I booted into recovery and can only see errors related to bluetooth, all of which can be ignored based on my findings, since they can't be related to my problem:

https://ibb.co/7K1YGLF

https://ibb.co/CmV8220

I can also boot into runlevel 3 without problems, but them I can't have GUI so this isn't a long term fix.

Booting using the previous kernel doesn't make any difference.

I also don't have Nvidia drivers at all.

Lastly I tried to reinstall Ubuntu via USB stick, but it doesn't detect my existing installation, probably because I have disk encryption enabled, so I can only delete everything and reinstall, which I want to avoid at all costs.

Anyway, I spend the whole day troubleshooting this and would really appreciate any help.

Edit: just reinstalled latest Ubuntu by deleting everything and see still got the same problem after reboot.

Edit2: Finally "fixed" by installing the LTS release instead.

Comment: Secure boot should be disabled.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I have enabled disk encryption and not secure boot. Also updated above.